# iphone app how to get around timer pausing when app is closed?

Tags: iphone, timer, background, nsdate

at the moment i am using a timer to perform a calculation and then update a label every second but once the iphone app is sent to the background the timer pauses and then resumes upon re-opening... what are my options to get around this so that it seems the timer has not stopped ??

--- at the moment trying to record the time in which the app stops and then reopens, that the difference between those values and add the difference to the label but having no luck :(

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED !!!

Comment: i think that u did the best solution ,because a timer can't work on background.

Comment: i dont know how to calculate the difference in time between when (applicationDidEnterBackground) and (applicationWillEnterForeground)......... this will allow me to work out how much time has been lost while the app has been in the background.

Answer (score 2):

When the app moves to the background (i.e. your app delegate gets the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` message, or you receive a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification), just stop the timer. And save the current time, if necessary.

Then when the app is moving to the foreground (i.e. your app delegate gets the `applicationWillEnterForeground:` message, or you receive a `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification), recalculate the the label value from the current time and then restart the timer.

Comment: this is helpful but i dont know how to calculate the difference in time between when (applicationDidEnterBackground) and (applicationWillEnterForeground)......... this will allow me to work out how much time has been lost while the app has been in the background.

Comment: @myles: Save the time in applicationDidEnterBackground (e.g. use `[NSDate date]` to get an NSDate object and then retain it in a property), and then in applicationWillEnterForeground use the date object's [`timeIntervalSinceNow` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceNow) to get the time difference.

Comment: @Anomie: i need something like... time2(when app eneters foreground) - time1(when app enters background) = time3(the difference in times)... this is so i can use this number(pref in seconds) to calculate the time i have lost while the app has been in background !! THANKS FOR THE HELP !!

Comment: @myles: That's what `timeIntervalSinceNow` gives you, except negative. Go read the documentation for details.

Comment: @Anomie: i can get the times to show up in the console using NSLog but i am getting lost when trying to display them in a label ??

Comment: @myles hunh? Then how did you show the time in a label in the first place? (<-- That's not to be rude or something, I don't understand the difference.)